Can the sum of integrals over infinitesimal intervals be made into an integral of an integral?
I am investigating the relationship between Hamilton's principle in physics and the Monge-Kantorovich theory of optimal transport in economics. I derived the action density formula in $R^2$ for a particle in a confined vortex, whose radius from the vortex core changes within the time domain, $t\in(0,T)$. For a velocity distribution in polar coordinates, $u_\theta (r,t)$, the Lagrangian integrals that compute the cost in kinetic energy for a particle to change its radius from some $r_0$ to $r_1$ is,
$$c(r_0, r_1)=\mathrm{inf}\left\{ \int_{r_0}^{r_1} \int_{0}^{T}L\left ( r,u_\theta ,t \right )dtdr  \right\}$$
which modifies an equation in Optimal Transport, Old and New (pg 347). If the particle's radius fluctuates "n" times between $t=0$ and $t=T$, the cost function becomes the summation,
\begin{align*}
    c_{total}&= \mathrm{inf}\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{r_{k-1}}^{r_k} \int_{0}^{T}L\left ( r,u_\theta ,t \right )dtdr \right\}\\
    &=\mathrm{inf}\left\{\int_{r_0}^{r_1} \int_{0}^{T}L\:dtdr +\int_{r_1}^{r_2} \int_{0}^{T}L\:dtdr+\dots + \int_{r_{n-1}}^{r_n} \int_{0}^{T}L\:dtdr \:\:,\:\:t\in(0,T) \right\}
\end{align*}
Question: How can these series of integrals in the summation be turned into an integral of the integral if we suppose the particle's radius is a smooth function of time, $r(t)∈[0,R_f)$ (for some boundary, $R_f$)?
Here is my attempt to formalize this:
\begin{align*}
    c_{total}&= \mathrm{inf}\left\{ \int_{r(0)}^{r(T)} \int_{0}^{T}L\left ( r,u_\theta ,t \right )dtdr \:\:,\:\: t\in(0,T),:\ r(t)\in [0,R_f) \right\}
\end{align*}
but I'm not sure if this is right.

Wouldn't [math.se] be a better place to ask this? While physically motivated it seems you are concerned more with the validation of a mathematical relationship than a physical one.

Can you clarify what is the $\rm inf()$ function or operator?

@RC_23 In mathematics it usually means the infimum.

There is the method of passing from the Fourier series to the Fourier integral or Fourier transformation, the double integral becomes a triple integral..., but we must see the conditions of application of this method.

https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/B11.LMA_.pdf
